# Yii2 Codeception - exceeded the timeout

Tags: unit-testing, yii2, phpunit, codeception

I run my unit tests in Jenkins server with a command composer.phar exec 'codecept run unit app/models' -vvv and get the following error:

> [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException]
>   The process "codecept run unit app/models" exceeded the timeout of
>   1800 seconds.

How can I fix it and allow tests to take more time? Thanks

Comment: How big is your test dump file? If the dump file is big, this increases the time considerably

Comment: Tests take me more than 10 minutes because I have lots of tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is a timeout of composer exec, execute codecept directly.
`./vendor/bin/codecept run unit app/models`

Comment: composer--global config process-timeout 9999